# NavigationDrawer isDrawerOpened always returns true

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout, android-compatibility

I have faced with weird problem. I am using navigation drawer from support library in my app.
Here is layout

```
   <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout_main_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/layout_drawer_left"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fillViewport="true">

    </ScrollView>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/layout_drawer_right"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:fillViewport="true" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And I find all views after setting content view.

```
private FrameLayout mLeftDrawerContainer, mRightDrawerContainer;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerMainLayout;
        mDrawerMainLayout = (DrawerLayout) rootBaseView.findViewById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
        mLeftDrawerContainer = (ScrollView) rootBaseView.findViewById(R.id.layout_drawer_left);
        mRightDrawerContainer = (ScrollView) rootBaseView.findViewById(R.id.layout_drawer_right);
```

I have tried a lot of ways in order to close drawer, it closes it visually, I mean everything is ok, drawer slowly left the screen and stays closed, but from perspective of code it always return true.

```
 protected boolean isDrawersOpened() {
    boolean rightDrawerOpened = mDrawerMainLayout.isDrawerOpen(mRightDrawerContainer);
    boolean leftDrawerOpened = mDrawerMainLayout.isDrawerOpen(mLeftDrawerContainer);
    return  rightDrawerOpened || leftDrawerOpened ;
}
```

Always true

```
public void closeDrawer() {
    mDrawerMainLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
    mDrawerMainLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    mDrawerMainLayout.closeDrawer(mRightDrawerContainer);
    mDrawerMainLayout.closeDrawer(mLeftDrawerContainer);
    mDrawerMainLayout.closeDrawers();
}
```

So it should work, but returns always true.

If it is bug in suppor library, no problems I will wait and use boolean variable inside activity to indicate this, but maybe someone dealt with the same problem.

Thank for any help and ideas in advance.

Comment: Have you tried checking by Gravity rather than views?

Comment: Surely, I have updated my question. I have missed this sorry

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, for my inattention.
I have made a mistake in my code

```
   if (hasLeftDrawer) {
        setupLeftDrawer();
    } else {
        mDrawerMainLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_OPEN, mLeftDrawerContainer);
    }
    if (hasRightDrawer) {
        setupRightDrawer();
    } else {
        mDrawerMainLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_OPEN, mRightDrawerContainer);
    }
```

Should be

```
    if (hasLeftDrawer) {
        setupLeftDrawer();
    } else {
        mDrawerMainLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED, mLeftDrawerContainer);
    }
    if (hasRightDrawer) {
        setupRightDrawer();
    } else {
        mDrawerMainLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED, mRightDrawerContainer);
    }
```